# live search using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to develop a live search application using php html and mysql. When i am running it i am getting an error

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) error in server.

Here is my html and php:

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
        <script   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function getStates(value) {
                $.post("mypage.php", {partialState: value}, function (data) {
                    $("#results").html(data);
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" onkeyup="getStates(this.value)" />
        <br>
        <div id="results"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

php:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost:3306", "root", "root") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("mydb") or die(mysql_error());
    $partialStates = $_POST['partialState'];
    $states = mysql_query("select name from software where name like '%        {$partialStates}%'");
    while ($state = mysql_fetch_array($states)) {
        echo"<div>" . $states['name'] . "</div>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Check out the location of this page `mypage.php`

Comment: mypage.php is in the same location as the html file.

Comment: try writing it like: `./mypage.php`

Comment: It is displaying ".$state['name'].""; } ?> below the search box in the div.

Comment: You don't have php interpreter

Comment: If you are working on windows try installing `WAMP` or `XAMP`

Comment: i have xamp. what do i need to do usiung that?

Comment: @KrishGambhir check some tutorials over net.

Comment: So in your computer have you tried to run any other php files? are they working? try to enter this in your address bar `http://localhost/dashboard/phpinfo.php`

Answer (score 2):

This works on my PC.
html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getStates(value){
  $.post("mypage.php", {partialState:value}, function(data){
    $("#results").html(data);
  });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" onkeyup="getStates(this.value)">
<br>
<div id="results"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

php:

```
<?php
$partialStates = $_POST['partialState'];
$query = 'SELECT name FROM software WHERE name LIKE "%'.$partialStates.'%"';
$mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1","root","root","mydb");
if($mysqli->connect_errno){
  echo "Keine Verbindung mit MySQL. :/";
}
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$data = $result->fetch_all();
foreach($data as $row){
  echo "<div>".$row[0]."</div>";
}
?>
```

If it's still not working:
  - ensure that both your mypage.php and your mypage.html are in the same directory
  -

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have installed Xampp / wamp. and then start apache, mysql in xamp. then paste your code into htdoc folder of xampp with your project name, then navigate to localhost/you_folder_name. 
try to change 
`echo"<div>" . $states['name'] . "</div>";` to 
`echo"<div>" . $state['name'] . "</div>";`

You are getting list of names form database which matches to typed string right?, so its sure not a single name. So I think it will return it as array.Try to use following code in your `mypage.php`.

```
 while ($state = mysql_fetch_array($states)) {
        echo"<div> <pre>" ;
        print_r ($states['name']); //or print_r($states); or echo $state['name'];
        echo "</pre></div>";
    }
```

I have written **or** in comment because I don't have any idea what you are getting in `$states`, it will be good if you some haw print array and paste it in your question.

Comment: man, you are assigning `$state` in while and echoing `$states` have you tried doing `print_r()`?

Comment: @MujahedAKAS cant see any change here `echo"<div>" . $states['name'] . "</div>"; to 
echo"<div>" . $state['name'] . "</div>";`

Comment: try  `echo"<div>`" ;
        print_r ($state);
        echo "`</div>";`

Comment: @MujahedAKAS firstly OP does not have PHP parser.

Comment: try this, `echo"<div>some dummy text</div>";`

Comment: btw i am running this on eclipse. So do i need to have anything else in eclipse?

Comment: eclipse is just an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

mypage.php

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("mydb") or die(mysql_error());
$partialStates = $_POST['partialState'];
$states = mysql_query("
select name from software where name like '%{$partialStates}%'");
while ($state = mysql_fetch_array($states)) {
echo"<div>" . $state['name'] . "</div>";
}
?>
```

[zxc][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVpJA.jpg

Honestly your script its work, the problem you make space between

from software where name like '%________{$partialStates}%'");

should : from software where name like '%{$partialStates}%'");

and
yours :

```
echo"<div>" . $states['name'] . "</div>";
```

change to:

```
 echo"<div>" . $state['name'] . "</div>";
```